# Is it possible to use an asp.net page to have the get results from the server sent back as an XML file?

Tags: asp.net

My application sending SMS request to Mblox XML interface through, I have get response from Mblox as XML file.

```
string RequestXML = GenerateRequestXML();

string uri = string.Empty; uri = "http://xml.us.mblox.com:8180/send"; 

HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

request.KeepAlive = false; 

request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11; 

request.Method = "POST";

request.ContentType = "text/xml";
HttpWebResponse respon = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()
```

Comment: You need to elaborate on your problem. Spend more than 30 seconds.

Comment: string RequestXML =  GenerateRequestXML();
string uri = string.Empty;
uri = "http://xml.us.mblox.com:8180/send";
HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.KeepAlive = false;        
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "text/xml";
HttpWebResponse respon = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Comment: "Post your code" means EDIT your original question and add the code, formatted as code (see one of the toolbar buttons above the edit text box). Do not post it as a comment, it is hard to read that much code when not properly formatted. Please do this, and delete the comment.

Comment: I Updated the Question, Please  can you send response

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there... You already have your response, just get a reference to ResponseStream and read the XML returned:

```
HttpWebResponse respon = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream receiveStream =    request.GetResponseStream();
Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
// Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader( receiveStream, encode );
//now you should be able to use readStream to get your XML. That's your homework.
```

[See a complete example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream.aspx)